# Add discount with cart in Shopify

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api

I have a Shopify site and I want to apply a discount for a product and I need to do this on the code side. I want to send the discount parameter in the 'data' object and see the automatic discount on the checkout page. When I look at the Shopify API (https://shopify.dev/api/), I only see the 'line_level_discount_allocations' parameter and there is no discount when I use it like the code example below. Which parameter do I need to send to the service with request for it to be Discount?

This article 'https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/discounts/discount-types' automatically generates discount (without using code). However, this does not solve the needs. I want to do it by using code and sending discount to request.

Source code:

```
 function sameValueCart(variant_id, qty, selling_plan) {  

 data = {
  "id": variant_id,
  "quantity": qty,
  "selling_plan": selling_plan,
  "line_level_discount_allocations": [
    {
      "amount": 20,
      "discount_application": {}
    }
  ]
}

var paramCart = '&cart_token=' + (document.cookie.match('(^|; )cart=([^;]*)')||0)[2];

jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/cart/add.js',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) { 
         var paramDomain = 'myshopify_domain={{ shop.permanent_domain }}';

        console.log('paramDomain', paramDomain);

        try {
            var paramLinker = "&" + ga.getAll()[0].get('linkerParam');
        } catch (err) {
            var paramLinker = '';
        }
        var paramCustomer = '{% if customer %}&email={{ customer.email }}{% endif %}';
        window.location.href = '/checkout';
}
});
}
```

Comment: use desired discount with checkout URL like `youstrore.com/checkout?discount=discount_code` it auto applies checkout page

Comment: read more about this parameters on [this Link](https://www.digismoothie.com/blog/shopify-custom-checkout-links)

Comment: @Onkar I don't want discount with URL and I just want to send with request (with data object). Do you have any comments about it?

Comment: it not possible into shopify